# Windows 98 suddenly unable to see the domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-domain, windows-98

I have a couple older computers running Windows 98. Not an option to upgrade. They are networked internally to a 2k3 server so that files can be transferred to them. Suddenly one of them has stopped being able to connect to the domain.

When the computer starts up and after I enter my password I get a message telling me that no domain server was found and I might not be able to access some resources.

The computer can ping the 2k3 server. It just cannot connect to the domain.

I have tried about all I can think of. Disable and re-enable WINS. Ditto with DNS. Uninstall tcp/ip and reinstall.

Nothing has changed in the past couple weeks that I know of on either end. The user for the 98 machine is not one to go poke and has no internet access.

Comment: ha. not one to go poke. hope it works out.... probably should upgprade it eventually though..

Comment: Try taking the machine off the domain and re-joining it...

Comment: Personally I would convert them to VMs and give the user something more modern to work on.

Comment: A vm would not work. These have to be 98/95 on actual hardware. They are feeding programs to cnc machines from the 70's over parallel port tape drive adapters and custom software.

Comment: In those days network cards were common rather than build in ethernet. Perhaps you can test if the network card is bad..  If you have another Win98 machine which is working properly then you could try swapping network cards and c if the working one stops working and the not working one starts working, then u know the network card had gone bad. If so, and if it takes a PCI network card, that's very cheap like less than $10 to replace off ebay (last time I checked, which was about 10 years ago).. That's if it is network card.If it's not then you could try making an image and reinstalling windows

Comment: Have any settings on the 2k3 machine changed? For example, has that machine been configured to deny LM Password Hashes, which are known to provide basically no security these days?

Comment: The machine can ping the server so I am thinking the ethernet port is good. (And this laptop is builtin). Nothing has changed on the 2k3 server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have images of the harddisk(s) of the machine, so you can go back to a working system? If it's a software problem, that might solve it.

- If you don't have an image of machine A, and you have an identical system B, make an image of machine B, and put that on machine A.
- Yes and of course before doing that, you need to make an image of machine A, and preferably take out that harddisk to prevent unnecessary changes, so you can go back in case the OS is not the problem.
- You can even swap system A to machine B, and see if that works to make sure the problem is not OS A.

Have proper working backups before doing this. Putting disk A in machine B can change disk A so it will not work in machine A when it's put back.

Comment: An ancient system with no more ability to fetch updates? Ofcourse the OP has backups of the system. Probably even in several different places. :)

Comment: You can assume all you want, but I don't see him mentioning anything about this. As well as he doesn't explain what these systems do, why they can't be upgraded. Let's hope you're right - but then I wonder why he hasn't tested this already?

Comment: No backups as such but all the software needed is backed up so a wipe and reinstall would not be the end of the world. Just annoying.

Comment: As for why they can't be upgraded they run custom VB6 code written well before I came here. They then write to the parallel port. Well in XP and up writing directly to the parallel port is much more difficult. While I could rewrite the code to work on more modern computers it would be a real pain because I am not a programmer. I know my way around VB.net and used to know java but not really any more. Although I do know enough to cringe a bit at how the program deals with timing. It runs a loop a number of times. Each computer has a different processor so the number is in a text box.

Comment: Isn't it much easier to hire a programmer that can fix this problem and make it easy to port to XP, maybe even to a VM? How much will that be?

Comment: Ah, that would be sane. But it would also cost money. And time. I suspect that the latter prevents it from being used as a current solution.